# UITextField apply filter to display

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have some `UITextField`s for entering currency amounts that display a number pad.  In my `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method I apply a currency nsnumberformatter to the `textField.text` and update it to display as a currency value.

The problem I run into is that once I apply the currency formatter to the inputted number and update the text property, I can't call `[textField.text floatValue]` any more.

I've thought about using the `tag` property of the `UITextField`s to hold their "actual" value, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not store it in another `float`? (as a global variable, or an ivar of the subclass, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

The tag property only holds an integer, so I doubt you really can do that. You can either hold it in an instance variable, as a part of an array, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **dictionary**, where **key** is currency identifier and **data** is a object containing formatted currency value, actual value and some other possibly needed data.